# How to fill in only the even indexes of an ArrayList?

Tags: java

So I was trying to produce an arraylist where the even indexes were all filled. Something like this [1, -, 1, -, 1, -........]. But it's giving me an index out of bounds error. Why is that?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Integer> a = new ArrayList<>(10);

        for (int i=0; i<11; i+=2) {
            a.add(i, new Integer(1234));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: change `i<11` `i<`0` to set 0 2, 4, 6, 8

Comment: Familiarize yourself with the modulo operator and try i%2

Comment: Because is something has a length of 10 in Java, then it only has elements 0-9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember indices always start with 0.
You've created an arraylist with size 10, which means you should iterate through index 9, not 10.

Your for loop should be:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i += 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Arrays use zero based indexing meaning you can reference a[0] through a[9]. so your constraint in the for loop
Should be i < 10. I’ll edit this answer and give more detail when I get home.

Answer (score 0):

First, you loop constraint is off, for an array (and `ArrayList`) of size 10, indices are 0 through 9, means you need to check for `i < 10`.
Second, the parameter of `ArrayList` constructor (10 in this case) is the *capacity*, but not *size* - it's still empty, no actual elements in there. So you need to add zeroes (or `null`s) in the loop too:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    if (i % 2 == 0) {
        a.add(1234);
    } else {
        a.add(0); // or a.add(null)
    }
}
```

Comment: So i fixed my code to loop through 0-9. But set doesn't work. ```import java.util.ArrayList;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Integer> a = new ArrayList<>(10);

        for (int i=0; i<10; i+=2) {
            a.add(i, new Integer(1234));
        }
    }
}```

Comment: @EDWINCHEN In which way it doesn't work? The line should be `a.set(i, new Integer(1234));`.

Comment: Its giving me a index out of bounds error

Comment: @EDWINCHEN Check it out

Comment: Please accept the answer if it helped solve the problem